# How to get COUNT value based on different column value?

Tags: sql, db2

Here is my query:

```
Select DISTINCT YEAR(THEDELIVERY) as YR,
(Select COUNT(*) from CS462MCMT.vehiclev1 where THEMAKE='Audi') as "No of Audis",
(Select COUNT(*) from CS462MCMT.vehiclev1  where THEMAKE='Volvo') as "No of Volvos",
(Select COUNT(*) from CS462MCMT.vehiclev1  where THEMAKE='Porche') as "No of Porsches",
(Select COUNT(*) from CS462MCMT.vehiclev1  where THEMAKE <> 'Audi' and THEMAKE <> 'Volvo' and THEMAKE <> 'Porche') as "No of Other"
from CS462MCMT.vehiclev1;
```

The first column displays the two distinct year values 2008 followed by 2007. I'm trying to get the count of each brand of car in the table based on the two distinct year values. I would like my output to look as follows (it currently has the same count values for both of the years 2008 and 2007):

```
Year No of Audis No of Volvos etc.
---- ----------- ------------
2008 1700        3000
2007  300        100
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use `GROUP BY` with a conditional `SUM` (`SUM` with `CASE`):

```
SELECT YEAR(THEDELIVERY) AS "Year",
    SUM(CASE THEMAKE WHEN 'Audi' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "No of Audis",
    SUM(CASE THEMAKE WHEN 'Volvo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "No of Volvos",
    SUM(CASE THEMAKE WHEN 'Porsche' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "No of Porsches",
    SUM(CASE WHEN THEMAKE NOT IN ('Audi','Volvo','Porsche') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        AS "No of Other"
FROM CS462MCMT.vehiclev1
GROUP BY YEAR(THEDELIVERY)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, I never would have thought of this.